# matplotlib interactive alteration of line properties

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I've been looking for a graphical / ipython console based means to turn lines on and off in a 2D graph generated with matplotlib, but I haven't found anything thus far.

Does anyone know a way to do something like this? What I have in mind specifically is incorporated in MATLAB, and can be seen here:

http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/creating_plots/plot_to5.html

All of the check boxes in the plot browser window will turn the lines on and off; their properties can also be altered graphically in another dialogue box. For now, I've been clicking on the properties button, and setting linetype to none, but this is cumbersome for a graph with many lines...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Vadim for your answer - you're right that the widgets provide an example with this functionality - to an extent. The example you provide doesn't give the graphical feedback I had in mind; instead, the widgets example closest to my request is actually check_buttons.py (see: http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/check_buttons.html)

Here, a side-box of labelled check buttons can be created, where upon clicking the checked buttons, it will turn the lines on and off - see the figure below. I suppose this could be built up into something along the lines of a plot browser like in matlab, but would require additional work to incorporate simple changes to the line style, etc.

I am still interested to know if someone has already done all of the work in making such functionality available; if not, I will post my best attempt when I get around to it.

[plot_browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYn5Z.png)

- I don't have sufficient rep points to add the image inline; my apologies.

Comment: The example you showed is exactly what I want, but how do I do it with histograms? Histograms don't return  line objects like pyplot.plot(x,y), right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there exists module named [`matplotlib.widgets`](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#module-matplotlib.widgets). There are some example [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/index.html). It allows you to do exactly what you asked for ([source](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/rectangle_selector.html)):
[image: All lines]
[image: Without one line]